# Why is my gradle task being called without a dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle task that I want to be ignored when printing the value of a variable. I don't understand why it's being called, and the value is changing.

```
def value = 'something'

task changeValue() {
value = 'somethingElse'
}

task printTask() {
    println "${value}"
}
```

Value being printed should be `something`. Why is `somethingElse` being printed out?

Edit:

Now I have

```
task changeValue() << {
value = 'somethingElse'
}
```

So this is only getting executed during execution phase.

But now if I change my print task to

```
task printTask(dependsOn: changeValue) {
    println "${value}"
}
```

I expect that `somethingElse` is printed. But now I only get `something` printed out.

Edit 2: forgot to add << in the printTask as well.

Comment: How are you executing your task?

Comment: you really need to take some time to understand the core concept of build lifecycle phases, see the link to the related documentation in the answer below.  if you don't make the difference between configuration and execution phases, you will probably loose lot of time writing/debugging your scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make my gradle plugin value depend on whether or not I execute another task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468013/how-do-i-make-my-gradle-plugin-value-depend-on-whether-or-not-i-execute-another)

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the gradle life cycle .  Checkout this link: [Build Lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)

Value in your task is changed during configuration phase. when we run a task then its execution phase start but its configuration phase run during build process.

Comment: thanks. I edited my question as now I have another issue

Comment: ah figured it out. missing << in the print task