# How do I make my gradle plugin value depend on whether or not I execute another task?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a task `changeValue` that I want to run optionally. Assume my plugin `somePlugin` has a task called `pluginTask`.

When I run `gradlew pluginTask` I want the value to be `someValue`.

When I run `gradlew changeValue pluginTask` I want the value to be `somethingElse`.

For the 2nd scenario, right now I still get `someValue`. It's being evaluated during gradle's configuration phase as opposed to execution phase. How can I resolve this?

```
 String value = 'someValue'

task changeValue() << {
value = 'somethingElse'
}  

somePlugin {
  source = ${value}
}
```

Comment: Is the "git" tag added by mistake?

Comment: @tryman yes sorry. removed it

Comment: @RonApple1996 I create 2 tasks `task changeValue() << {value ='somethingElse'}` and `task getValue() << {println "V = $value"}` and command `gradlew changeValue getValue` works correctly. Can you add code of your plugin task?